# jQuery - Cannot Click on Item in DOM Because of Margin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having problems getting jQuery to click on the images in the footer because of the `margin: -107px 0 0 0;` style applied to the footer. I don't understand why this is causing a problem as I can still see the images in the DOM when I inspect the website. I also noticed that I am having problems highlighting the words "Grilled Chicken Pesto Sandwich" in the footer, and I believe this is also because of the `margin: -107px 0 0 0;` style applied to the footer.

[Link to website](http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/la1/template.html)

```
//jQuery
$("footer #thumbs ul li figure img").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.backstretch(images[id]);
  $('html').css('background-size', 'cover');    
});

//css
footer {
  margin: -107px 0 0 0; //The -107px is causing the problem
  width: 100%;
  height: 107px;
  background: url(../img/bottom.png) repeat-x;
}

//html
<footer>
  <div id="thumbsDesc">Grilled Chicken Pesto Sandwich</div>
  <div id="thumbs">
    <ul>
      <li><figure><img id="0" src="img/01.jpg"></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img id="1" src="img/02.jpg"></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img id="2" src="img/03.jpg"></figure></li>
      <li><figure><img id="3" src="img/04.jpg"></figure></li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: As a side note, making your user download 2.5MB of images leads to very poor load performance. Shrink those images down (One is 2486*2242).

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you for the reminder. I was testing on my local so the size did not effect me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrease the z-index of the wrapper class, I tried this on firebug and I was able to select the text and click the images. No need to increase foot z-index
I used -10 for the wrapper

Edit: also if you remove the position relative on the wrapper, it works too so you can do whatever you think is best suited for all browser, I only played with this on FF

Answer (score 2):

For the div marked `id="thumbs"` set its css to

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 120px;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `div class="wrapper"` overlays the *footer*. *(Try to change `z-index` of the footer.) -- doesn't work, sorry.* Try to put footer inside the wrapper.

Comment: This is definitely the problem, however the solution doesn't quite work. You will need to do more than just that.

Comment: How come `wrapper` overlays the `footer` when I can visually see the footer on top of the wrapper?

Travis is correct - I changed the z-index but it still did not work.

Comment: I need the `footer` to be outside of the `wrapper` to ensure that the footer stays glued to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: It overlays it with transparent space. Like pane of glass over the button.